# terraform - split variable value into 2

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable (var.http_proxy) that holds proxy details (ip address : port). I am setting env variable to a lambda and I have 2 variable , host and port. Now I need to use split the variable and assign proxy host and port instead of defining 2 new variables. I am using the code below and it is wrong -

```
environment = {
    variables = {
      proxy_host = "${split(":", var.http_proxy)[0]}"
      proxy_port = "${split(":", var.http_proxy)[1]}"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to add **RESOLVED** to the title or to edit the solution into your question. Your answer below is sufficient. You can even accept it as correct if you choose to do so.

Comment: Sure , Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below fix resolved this -

```
  proxy_host = "${element(split(":", var.http_proxy),0)}"
  proxy_port = "${element(split(":", var.http_proxy),1)}"
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. split creates a list but you cannot access it as an iterable list with `[0]` as that is only available to resources created using count.